# Como obtener ultimo caracter o letra de un string

Tags: php, url

estoy tratando de obtener el ultimo numero despues de el ultimo **dash** es decir la ultima rallita `-`de una cadena como esta

```
Profesores-de-Barahona-demandan-calidad-del-almuerzo-escolar-y-mejorar-plantas-fsicas-3
```

esta cadena proviene de una **URL** el cual el ultimo numero es el **id** de el **post** por lo tanto nececito extraer ese id para luego hacer una consulta a la base de datos intente con `explode` de esta manera pero me devuelve desde el primer **dash** `-`

```
$id=explode("-",$_GET["view"]);
```

esto me devuelve `de`

alguna idea de como **extraer** ese ultimo numero?  gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente:

```
<?php

$cadena = "Profesores-de-Barahona-demandan-calidad-del-almuerzo-escolar-y- 
           mejorar-plantas-fsicas-3";

echo substr($cadena, strrpos($cadena, '-') + 1);

//RESULTADO 3
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. `substr` devuelve la parte espefícica de una cadena
2. `strrpos` obtiene la última posición donde aparece `-`
3. al usar `+1` obtenemos el valor que esta después del ultimo `-` que en este caso es el número 3

Comment: Genial!, gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tu $GET['view'] es una cadena:

```
<?php
 $cadena = "Profesores-de-Barahona-demandan-calidad-del-almuerzo-escolar-y-mejorar-plantas-fsicas-3";
 $part=explode("-",$cadena); 
 $id = end($part);
 var_dump($id);exit();
```

con la funcion end() de php obtienes el ultimo elemento de un array

Answer (score 2):

Si todas tus `URL` van a tener al final el `id` que necesitas puedes hacer simplemente lo siguiente:

```
$cadena = "Profesores-de-Barahona-demandan-calidad-del-almuerzo-escolar-y-mejorar-plantas-fsicas-3";
$id = substr($cadena, -1);
echo $id;
```

Guardas en `$id` el numero que deseas para después utilizarlo donde quieras. Saludos.